# Ошибка подключения к серверу

Tags: sql-server

```
"Не удается подключиться к %server-name%\SQLEXPRESS.
Ошибка при подключении к серверу. При подключении к SQL Server 2005 эта ошибка может быть вызвана тем, что стандартные параметры SQL Server не разрешают удаленные подключения. (provider: Сетевые интерфейсы SQL, error: 26 - Ошибка при обнаружении указанного сервера или экземпляра) (Microsoft SQL Server, ошибка: -1)"
```

Что не так?

Answer (score 1):

Судя по всему - удаленные подключения к SQL Server'у запрещены. Попробуйте подключиться с локальной машины.
[Здесь](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/kb/914277#method1) написано, как это сделать.